# hide soft keyboard upon opening searchable spinner

Tags: xamarin.android, android-spinner, android-softkeyboard

i created an android app via xamarin.android. i have a searchable spinner with list of items. my problem is that when i click on the spinner the keypad directly opens without having to touch the search space. i tried removing the text pointer by removing the focus when opening the spinner but it didn't work. i tried hiding the keyboard programmatically using this code:

```
if(vehicle_spinner.Pressed==true)
 {
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(vehicle_spinner.WindowToken(), 0);
}
```

but it didn't work too. i tried changing `vehicle_spinner.Pressed` to `vehicle_spinner.Selected` but no result. what should i do? thanks in advance.

Comment: What is searchable spinner? Xamarin.Android.SearchableSpinner or other?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT no it's ```Com.Toptoche.Searchablespinnerlibrary```